# Choosing the right op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]I'm thinking of using an op-amp in a measurement circuitry. The sample will be in series with the op-amp and will be subjected to at most 50V AC (amplitude) at a maximum of 324kHz (although more likely at 60Vpp and 324kHz).

I'm not sure what to look for in my op-amp or if the fact that I'm applying such high voltages and frequencies to my sample will be a factor in choosing an op-amp.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction towards choosing the right op-amp! Thanks.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it'll be used as current-to-voltage converter.

EDIT: Here is the circuitry that I will be building. The sample here refers to my dielectric sample.

Comment: What is the expected current range?

Comment: Those voltages are unusually high; what sort of impedance does the sample have? (& therefore how much power will you be driving into it)

Comment: Nice robust current-to-voltage converters are available under the heading of "resistors" (or "shunts" if there's a lot of current.)

Comment: The expected current range is <0.1A. This stems from the fact that the sample is a piezoelectric material. So any current induced will be small.

Comment: It might be good to have one that can go "rail-to-rail".

Comment: Less than 0.1 A is not really useful or helpful. No transimpedance amp that I'm aware of will be able to cope with that much current. Maybe you meant 0.1mA?

Comment: Sorry for those who've read this. My mistake - it should really be less than 80mA.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to be concerned about the voltage that the op-amp will actually see, both when negative feedback is intact, and  when negative feedback is broken.  If you use a "typical" transimpedance amplifier (i.e., current to voltage converter), shown below, for example, so long as you choose the resistor such that the output voltage never exceeds the capabilities of the op-amp, then both of the input terminals will be at zero volts (the inverting input as a "virtual ground"), and everything is OK.  If your op amp needs to go above its output capabilities to keep feedback going, all bets are off about what the voltage can be at the inverting terminal, and you can damage your op amp. There are a variety of methods available to "clamp" your input to the range that won't damage your op amp should feedback failure occur, like zener diodes.  Your output won't be indicative of the current input, but it won't break.

Alternatively, you might be able to find an op amp that works across the voltage you may see during open loop behavior.

[image: from c2.staticflickr.com/4/3444/3363369386_8882277623.jpg]

from c2.staticflickr.com/4/3444/3363369386_8882277623.jpg

Answer (score 1):

100mA is too large to reasonably source from the op-amp output so I suggest a modest value ground-referenced sense resistor (perhaps 1 ohm or 10 ohms) that will give you a measurement of the current without unduly affecting the 60V signal.

A bit of series impedance and a diode clamp (1N4148s) will protect the amplifier, and you can amplify the signal up to several volts if you like.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH6x7y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At one ohm, you'll have up to 100mV to work with. A gain of 10~100 should be suitable, so you'll want an op-amp with GBW of maybe 50-100MHz. R3 should be a low inductance 5W resistor if you want it to survive a direct short to 50VAC (*not* wirewound because the inductance would affect the measurement). A series-parallel arrangement of 4 510 ohm 2512 2W resistors would do the job inexpensively.

Edit: As Scott says, make sure slew rate is adequate for the job:

\$f_{max} = \frac{S_r}{2\pi Vp}\$, so if Vp is 5V you need a slew rate of at least 10V/usec. Most, if not all, op-amps with 50-100MHz GBW will meet that requirement.

The other thing to watch out for is open-loop gain. For reasonable accuracy at a gain of 100, you probably want open-loop gain to be 100dB or so. Many high frequency amplifiers don't meet that requirement. It would also be nice to have it unity-gain stable. Also many modern amplifiers can't stand much supply voltage, so take care in that respect.

Comment: Slew rate can be as important as GBW product here.

Comment: In what way are you using `Rs` in this configuration? Also, why exactly have you placed `D1` and `D3`? (Particularly in parallel reverse)

Comment: @sherrellbc Rs is the sense resistor. E = I * R. D1 and D3 keep the voltage at the inverting input of the amplifier from exceeding about +/-1V even under fault conditions. The output voltage is Iin * Rs * (1+(R2/R1)) under normal conditions.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks for your answer. But the current value should be ~80mA (max). Would this still be too large for transimpedance amps to handle?

Comment: @user3771106 That's still pretty high. LMH6624 comes close, but it has lousy open-loop gain and will result in a fairly large and inductive-looking input impedance (ideal is 0\$\Omega\$, but you won't get that).

Comment: @user3771106 Suggest you calculate either way and use the method that seems to work the best. You can use the back-to-back diodes with the transimpedance configuration, but of course it might not survive a direct short. Make sure you have a high frequency oscilloscope available, the "hot" amplifiers do like to oscillate.